# Possible to create anonymous non-const char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, constants

I'm working with an older C++ compiler that does not have `std::to_string(...)` in its STL. I would like to stringify an integer, so I think I'm stuck with `char*  itoa (int value, char* str, int base)`. I want to avoid creating a named `char[]` to use as the second argument to `itoa()`. Can this be done?

I'm aware that I could do

```
itoa(5, "abcd", 10)
```

But this is actually incorrect since "abcd" is actually a `const char[]`, and I suspect the resulting behavior is at best undefined. Of course, casting away the constness is unacceptable.

Is there any way to pass an anonymous *non-const* char[] in the argument list to a function? I tooled around with the syntax in various attempts, but couldn't come up with anything. I looked around online including StackOverflow, and didn't encounter any Q&A that quite covered this.

Thanks for guidance.

**UPDATE:**

I neglected to mention in the original post: I also need the char[] to be on the stack, i.e. `new`ing/`malloc`ing a char[] isn't an option for this exercise.

**UPDATE 2:**

I've gotten some requests for context, so here goes:

*To reiterate: I'm stuck with an older compiler that doesn't support `std::to_string(...)`*

I would liked to have done:

```
std::string foo(std::string(itoa(42, < *** non-const stack-allocated char[] *** > , 10)))
```

I.e. all I really want to do is construct a `std::string` with the stringification of an integer.

Why? Ok, even more context:

I'm trying to create a named semaphore, and name it  appended by pid. So the call would theoretically look something like:

```
sem_open(std::string(typeinfo(*this).name()).append(std::string(itoa(getpid(), < *** non-const stack-allocated char[] *** >, 10))))
```

Any why do I want to do things this way?

> Looks to me like this might be the case of missing the forest for the trees

Perhaps. This is partly an academic exercise, I just crave to know if it's within the C++ syntax to do this. But beyond that, there is an element of code hygiene by avoiding heap allocation: I might certainly forget to `delete[]` the `char` in my destructor. Moreover, the lifetime of my hypothetical `char[]` really only needs to be for the creation of the semaphore. Wouldn't it be nice to syntactically guarantee it only lives for as long as it needs to? This is what RAII is after all, so ultimately this question is whether RAII can be implemented for this specific situation.

Thanks again for answers and comments.

**UPDATE 3**

Thank you, everyone, for your answers. I recognize and understand the answers that were given, but I was hoping to find an answer that also avoided wrapper functions. It was my negligence that I did not mention this in the original question. This question was perhaps badly phrased to start with; I should have started by revealing the context was to create a semaphore which might have also steered commenters differently. I try to phrase my questions succinctly and accurately, but my attempt to simplify the problem statement ended up leaving relevant context; sorry about that..

I have, though, just wrought out an ungodly answer of my own. I may have officially dived into [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/) territory, though:

```
sem_open(std::string(typeinfo(*this).name()).append(static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << getpid()).str().c_str()))
```

Comment: Can you use std::ostringstream instead of std::to_string ?

Comment: @M.M: Updated with fuller context.

Comment: @StoneThrow ok, o11c's solution is what you are looking for then. The buffer is "stack" and doesn't live past the calling expressoin

Comment: you *could* write `&std::array<char, 500>()[0]` in your complicated expression but that is rather poor style. Readability is your friend

Comment: You may want to look into "string-printf" type functions too, e.g.syntax would be `stprintf("% %", typeinfo(*this).name(), getpid());` and returning a `std::string`

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like this might be the case of missing the forest for the trees.

As I understand your question, your are attempting to implement a replacement for `std::to_string`, because your compiler does not have it.

And you would like to implement it for the use case of a simple `int` conversion.

Just have your wrapper function resize a `std::vector<char>` sufficiently, use it for the `char *` buffer for your conversion, then just construct a `std::string` from the buffer, that your replacement function returns.

And, for a pure C++ solution:

```
std::string int_to_string(int n)
{
    std::ostringstream o;

    o << n;

    return o.str();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't take the address of a anonymous temporary and keep it alive, except possible with some hacks involving named *references*, but those don't work with arrays.

So, you fundamentally need to use to a named array. But, you can wrap it in a *function* call that returns a `std::string` anyway.

```
std::string my_to_string(int val, int base)
{
    /* Big enough buffer for base=2. */
    char buf[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT + 1];
    (void)itoa(val, buf, base);
    return buf;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could dynamically allocate the string.

```
char *result = itoa(5, new char[5], 10);
```

But you'll have to remember to use:

```
delete[] result;
```

Comment: Darn, you answered just before I realized I didn't specify that I need the char[] to be on the stack. I'm going to update my question, but thank you for the answer.

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck. What's so bad about declaring a local variable? Why are people so obsessed with one-liners?

Comment: Let me update my question with a little more context. It's not that I'm obsessed with one-liners per say, but, if this had been possible, it would have complied with the RAII principle, which I try to use as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to avoid dynamic allocation you can't use `std::string` except if you can be sure that for all relevant compilers it uses the short buffer optimization and that for all relevant compilers that fixed buffer is large enough for all possible use cases. But lets just say, you can't use `std::string`.

Then creating a stack based buffer is easy enough. `std::numeric_limits<int>` tells you the maximum number of decimal digits. However, since you're using an older compiler it probably does not support `constexpr`. So just calculate this using the statically known values from `<limits.h>`. Add 1 for sign and you have the maximum number of characters. Add 1 for zero termination and you have your buffer size N.

Now create a class `Stringified` with an internal buffer of N `char`, and a constructor that takes the `int` (and possibly also a base) as argument.

You can use that class to create a temporary (it lasts until the end of the full-expression) or to create a variable, in both cases completely stack based, e.g. like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <limits>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

bool hopefully( bool const condition ) { return condition; }
bool fail( std::string const& s ) { throw std::runtime_error( s ); }

int const n_digits_of_int =
    //std::numeric_limits<int>::digits10() + 1;
    1+ 3*CHAR_BIT*sizeof( int )/10;

class Stringified
{
private:
    enum{ buffer_size = n_digits_of_int + 2 };
    char    buffer[buffer_size];
public:
    char const* c_str() const { return buffer; }

    explicit Stringified( int const value )
    {
        int const n_chars = sprintf( buffer, "%d", value );
        hopefully( n_chars > 0 )
            || fail( "Stringified::<init>: failed to convert value" );
    }
};

int main()
{
    printf( "%s\n", Stringified( 42 ).c_str() );
}
```